# Change body width using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen

I just came to know that we can find out the screen resolution of our users using screen.width and screen.height etc. But is there any way to have a variable body width. I mean can i set the body width property using jquery or javascript. This is gonna change with the resolution of every user so that my site seems perfect in all of them...

Can anyone help me in having code to set the width(CSS) of my page according to the value obtained through Jscript above.

Thanks

Comment: let us know if you need more info

Comment: You should consider `screen.availWidth`, because things like the Windows taskbar can use up some of the space reported by `screen.width`. Also, make sure you test it with a PC hooked up to multiple monitors. Last time I used screen.width it got a bit confused when more than one screen was connected. (From memory I think screen.width gave the width of the first monitor, and screen.availWidth gave the combined width of both. Or was it the other way around? If the monitors were set to different resolutions it got really confused. This probably varies amongst different browsers.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the body with JavaScript...

```
document.body.style.width = '700px';
```

...or if you are using jQuery...

```
$('body').css('width', '700px');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use jquery and do it through .css

```
$('body').css('width', '1000px');
```

[`css()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).